# Scala Return statement behaviour

Tags: scala, conditional-statements

I have defined one method below .

```
def diff(x:Int,y:Int)={ if (x>y) (x+y).toString else x-y }
```

It is working fine.

If I use return statement like below it is throwing an error

```
def diff(x:Int,y:Int)={if (x>y) return (x+y).toString else return x-y}
```

> result need return type

The below code is working, when I am defining type explicitly, `Any`.
Why is this not inferring as `any` when I don't define result type explicitly?

```
def diff(x:Int,y:Int):Any={if (x>y) return (x+y).toString else return x-y}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a return is present within a method, Scala can't know the type of that return at the point (since it may be more returns as in your example).

So Scala's compiler would have to check the whole method to look for more exit points (return). This will increase the complexity and the time expended in compilation and inferring types.

The solution given by the compiler to avoid this is to make compulsory define the output type if return is present.

You can avoid returns and the type will be inferred:

Quick example here

**Return without explicit Type**

```
def myFunc(x: Int) = return x+1
<console>:7: error: method myFunc has return statement; needs result type
       def myFunc(x: Int) = return x+1
```

**No return, type is properly inferred**

```
scala> def myFunc(x: Int) = x+1
myFunc: (x: Int)Int
```

**Return with explicit type**

```
scala> def myFunc(x: Int): Int = return x+1
myFunc: (x: Int)Int
```

Answer (score 0):

Scala functions do not require an explicit `return`. The last expression in the function body is usually interpreted as the return value of the function call.

Rewrite your function like this:

```
def diff(x:Int,y:Int): Any = {
    if (x>y) (x+y).toString
    else scalax-y
}
```

Your second function throws an error because as you can clearly see from the error message, scala is confused (and rightfully so) as to what the return type of your function is. Your function returns either a `String` or `Int` depending on the condition, so you need to give scala an explicit type.

According to this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35471931/2089675), Scala will not infer `Any` when the type can be generalized to something more concrete than `Any`.